# Rounding to two specific times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will round to either a time 15 minutes or 45 minutes past the hour based on the minutes in a time.. 
Example:  If I have a time in A1 and the minutes are 46 and 14, I want the formula to return the time of 15 past the hour.
If A1 has 11:47 then return 12:15. 
If I have a time in A1 and the minutes are between 16 and 44, I want the formula to return the time of 45 past the hour.
If A1 has 12:23 then return a time of 12:45
Any time that is either 15 or 45 past the hour will not change.

Comment: Looks like the easiest way would be to have 3 different cases, 0-15 = 15, 16-45 = 45, and 46-59 = 15 (next hour).

Answer (score 3):

```
=CEILING(A1+TIME(0,15,0),TIME(0,30,0))-TIME(0,15,0)
```

- Add 15 minutes
- Roundup to the nearest 30 minutes
- Subtract 15 minutes

Comment: Nice answer.  I like how you used the 2nd CEILING parameter.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ Thank you.  It's a bit shorter, and arguably easier to understand, than using ROUNDUP, for which the equivalent algorithm would be  =ROUNDUP((A1+TIME(0,15,0))/(TIME(0,30,0)),0)*TIME(0,30,0)-TIME(0,15,0).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated but... (**updated**)

```
=(CEILING((A1-(15/(24*60)))/(1/48), 1)*(1/48))+(15/(24*60))
```

It goes something like this:

1. Subtract 15m to the time
2. Divide by 30m
3. Round up this value
4. Multiply by 30m
5. Add 15m

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula using the logic from my comment above:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=0,A1<=15),15,(IF(AND(A1>15,A1<=45),45,15)))
```

Remember, you will also need to add 1 to the hour in the final case (where A1 > 45).

Here is a breakdown of the above formula:

```
1. If A1 is between 0-15, then it will return 15.
2. If A1 is between 16-45, then it will return 45.
3. If A1 is between 46-59, then it will return 15. (the logic to add an hour is not handled in this formula)
```